# Parsing csv to multidimensional array

Tags: python, csv

I'm having trouble parsing a csv into a multi-dimension array.
Below is my last attempt and a snippet of the data. All the csv files are structured the same way, but have different number of rows.

In the end, I need to be able to call `rawTime[][]` and return a value.

```
fileNames = ['LT6105-50M.txt', 'LT6105-20M.txt', 'LT6105-10M.txt', 'LT6105-5M.txt']

rawTime = [[[0 for col in range(3)]for row in range(1)] for x in range(1)]
rawData = [[[0 for col in range(3)]for row in range(1)] for x in range(1)]
rawCurrent = [[[0 for col in range(3)]for row in range(1)] for x in range(1)]
#rawLabels = []

rangeIndex = 0
for i in range(0, len(fileNames)):
    dataFile = open(fileNames[i], "r")
    rLoadindex = 0

    try:
        reader = csv.reader(dataFile, delimiter='\t')
        #Ignore header
        dataFile.next()

        #Start parsing lines
        for row in reader:
            try:
                rawTime.append([rangeIndex, rLoadindex, float(row[0])])
                rawData.append([rangeIndex, rLoadindex, float(row[1])])
                rawCurrent.append([rangeIndex, rLoadindex, float(row[2])])

            except:
                matchObj = re.search( r'Rload=[0-9.]+K', row[0])
                if matchObj:
                    #print  "Match: ", matchObj.group()
                    #rawLabels.append(matchObj.group())

                    rLoadindex = rLoadindex + 1
                else:
                    print "No match found", str(row)
                    pass

        #Done parsing per file
        rangeIndex = rangeIndex + 1

    finally:
        dataFile.close()
```

Sample data:

```
time    V(out)  I(R8)
Step Information: Rload=350K  (Run: 1/19)
0.000000000000000e+000  0.000000e+000   0.000000e+000
7.812500091297636e-010  5.023578e-008   5.580119e-010
Step Information: Rload=330K  (Run: 2/19)
0.000000000000000e+000  -1.627455e-002  -6.274048e-013
7.812500091297636e-010  -1.627346e-002  5.912035e-010
1.562500018259527e-009  -1.627140e-002  1.183048e-009
```

Current output:

`[[0, 1, 3.125000036519054e-09], [0, 1, 6.250000073038109e-09], [0, 1, 1.250000014607622e-08] ...]`

The problem is the data isn't accessible using the following format: `rawTime[0][1] should return 3.125000036519054e-09`

Another example of why my code isn't working:

```
for rangeIndex in range(0, len(rawTime)):
    for rLoadIndex in range(0, len(rawTime[rangeIndex])):
            print ('%d, %d, %f' %(rangeIndex, rLoadIndex,   rawTime[rangeIndex][rLoadIndex]) )
```

I expect the result from the sample data I provided:
`0, 0, 0.000`
`0, 1, 7.8125e-010`
`1, 0, 0.000`
`1, 1, 7.8125e-010`
`1, 2, 1.5625e-009`

Instead, this is my output I see:

```
0, 0, 0.000000
0, 1, 1.000000
0, 2, 0.000000
1, 0, 0.000000
1, 1, 1.000000
1, 2, 0.000000
2, 0, 0.000000
2, 1, 1.000000
2, 2, 0.000000
```

Comment: You need the `Step Information: Rload=330K  (Run: 2/19)` info, right? Or are the times enough?

Comment: What is wrong anyhow? An Error, wrong data... how should the output for the given input should look like?

Comment: You should [edit] your question and add at least one more sample of input data, _plus_ show the current and/or desired output.

Comment: ppasler, I do need to know the Rload value. I'm able to parse that. I'm just ignoring it until I can get the rest of the values (time, data, current).

Comment: rawTime[0][1] should return 1, rawTime[0][2] should return the value you are looking for if your "current output" is correct.

Comment: @wobbily_col yes, that works. But take a look at the code to loop through the range and rLoad.